# How to pass a parameter in twiml.gather?

Tags: node.js, twilio

I just started using Twilio and Javascript. I am using Twilio's Function product, and am trying to pass an argument from my `voice-ivr` to my `handle-user-input` function. I tried to do so by passing the parameter in the action URL, but that doesn't seem to be working. Any idea as to why it isn't working or if there is a better way to pass arguments between these two functions?

Here is my `voice-ivr` file:

```
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback,) {
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  const gather = twiml.gather({
    numDigits: 1,
    action: 'handle-user-input?room=0',
    hints: 'room 1, room 2',
    input: 'speech dtmf',
  });
  
  gather.say('Press 1 to go to Room 1 or 2 to go to Room 2.');
  twiml.say(`Sorry we couldn't understand you`);
  twiml.redirect();
  callback(null, twiml);
};
```

And my `handle-user-input` file:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  let UserInput = event.Digits || event.SpeechResult;
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  // No User Input
  if (!UserInput) {
    twiml.say('Sorry something went wrong. Please call again');
    return callback(null, twiml);
  }

  if (UserInput.length > 1) {
    if (UserInput.toLowerCase().includes('room 1')) {
      UserInput = '1';
    } else if (UserInput.toLowerCase().includes('room 2')) {
      UserInput = '2';
    }
  }
 
  var room_number = getUrlVars()["room"];
 
  // User Input is a digit: move to according room
  switch (room_number) {
    case 1:
      switch (UserInput) {
      case '1':
        twiml.say("Thank you. You will now be forwarded to room 2.")
        twiml.redirect('room-2');
        break;
      case '2':
        twiml.say('Thank you. You will now be forwarded to the home.');
        twiml.redirect('voice-ivr');
        break;
      default:
        twiml.say('We are sorry, we did not recognize your option. Please try again.');
        twiml.redirect('room-1');
      }
      break;
      
    case 2: 
      switch (UserInput) {
      case '1':
        twiml.say("Thank you. You will now be forwarded to the home.")
        twiml.redirect('voice-ivr');
        break;
      default:
        twiml.say('We are sorry, we did not recognize your option. Please try again.');
        twiml.redirect('room-2');
      }
      break;
      
    default:
    twiml.say("Default case");
      switch (UserInput) {
      case '1':
        twiml.say("Thank you. You will now be moved to Room 1.")
        twiml.redirect('room-1');
        break;
      case '2':
        twiml.say('You are now entering Room 2.');
        twiml.redirect('room-2');
        break;
      default:
        twiml.say('We are sorry, we did not recognize your option. Please try again.');
        twiml.redirect('voice-ivr');
      }
  }

  callback(null, twiml);
  }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL query parameter, `?room=0` is passed into the Twilio Function (when the Gather verb calls the action URL) in the event object, so you access it using `event.room`.

Also, since you are not using `speech`, you should remove it from the Gather attributes.

You are using Node.js, so there is no Window object.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! Just as a note for others trying this, the type of `event.room` is a string, not an int.